# MEF - Share interface without referencing the main project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mef

I'm new with MEF and I coudn't find an anwesr to my question.

I'm trying to create a MEF application where everyone can add certain plugin to it, for what I've seen you can create a libary with the plugin using the Interface to communicate. My question how can I share this interface without referencing the original project, lets say for example I give the builed program to a friend and he wants to add a plugin to it.

I may be wrong in how this work but I would really like it so anyone can add plugins without the source code.

For the particular plugin in question All it needs to do is recive a String, change some things and return a new String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, instead of one main project you have two:

1. The "core" dll project
2. The "app" project

Then you have the interfaces in "core" as well as any helpful classes (utilities etc) that plugins may need, and you put the implementation in the "app" project.

So, you end up with.

1. "core" project
2. "app" project

   1. This references "core"
3. "plugin" project

   1. This references "core"
   2. This exports the interface found in "core"

Comment: Well that was simple, and it worked, thanks!